# Unable to plot confidence intervals using ggplot, (geom_ribbon() argument)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, geom-ribbon

I am trying to plot 95% confidence intervals on some simulated values but am running into so issues when i am trying to plot the CIs using the geom_ribbon() argument. The trouble I'm having it that my model does not show the CIs when i plot them, like so;
[image]

I have included all of my code below if anyone knows where i have gone wrong here;

```
set.seed(20220520)  
#simulating 200 values between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution
x = runif(200, min = 0, max = 1) 

lam = exp(0.3+5*x)

y = rpois(200, lambda = lam)

#before we do this each Yi may contain zeros so we need to add a small constant
y <- y + .1 
#combining x and y into a dataframe so we can plot
df = data.frame(x, y)

#fitting a Poisson GLM
model2 <- glm(y ~ x, 
          data = df,
          family = poisson(link='log'))

#make predictions (this may be the same as predictions_mod2)
preds <- predict(model2, type = "response")

#making CI predictions
predictions_mod2 = predict(model2, df, se.fit = TRUE, type = 'response')

#calculate confidence intervals limit
upper_mod2 = predictions_mod2$fit+1.96*predictions_mod2$se.fit 
lower_mod2 = predictions_mod2$fit-1.96*predictions_mod2$se.fit

#transform the CI limit to get one at the level of the mean
upper_mod2 = exp(upper_mod2)/(1+exp(upper_mod2)) 
lower_mod2 = exp(lower_mod2)/(1+exp(lower_mod2))

#combining into a df
predframe = data.frame(lwr=lower_mod2,upr=upper_mod2, x = df$x, y = df$y)

#plot model with 95% confidence intervals using ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = predframe, aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x, preds2), col = 'blue')
```

Comment: Can you provide the object `aids` in your predict function?

Comment: Apologies, this should read 'df', has now been updated in the question.

Comment: What is `preds` in your geom_line command?

Comment: ahh, yes i left out this line of making the predictions, although i think this should actually read 'predictions_mod2' after looking again. Should hopefully be free of errors now

Comment: Still some error in your example. Anyway, try this for your geom_ribbon: `geom_ribbon(data = predframe, aes(ymin=preds-lwr, ymax=preds+upr), fill='green')`

Comment: predframe - `predframe = data.frame(lwr=lower_mod2,upr=upper_mod2, x = df$x, y = df$y, preds=predictions_mod2$fit)`

Comment: Do **not**, like you say in a code comment, *#transform the CI limit to get one at the level of the mean*.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for this, do you mind if i ask why this would be a problem?         So i can just my original '#calculate confidence intervals limit' predictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423458/unable-to-plot-confidence-intervals-using-ggplot-geom-ribbon-argument?noredirect=1#comment127945975_72423458) to the question, it's asked why not to logit transform the predicted values. The reason why is that the type of prediction asked for is `"response"`. From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html), my emphasis.

> type
> the type of prediction required. The default is on the scale of the linear predictors; **the alternative "response" is on the scale of the response variable**. Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds (probabilities on logit scale) and type = "response" gives the predicted probabilities. The "terms" option returns a matrix giving the fitted values of each term in the model formula on the linear predictor scale.

There is a good way to answer, to show the code.

```r
library(ggplot2, quietly = TRUE)

set.seed(20220520)  
#simulating 200 values between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution
x = runif(200, min = 0, max = 1) 

lam = exp(0.3+5*x)

y = rpois(200, lambda = lam)

#before we do this each Yi may contain zeros so we need to add a small constant
y <- y + 0.1 
#combining x and y into a dataframe so we can plot
df = data.frame(x, y)

#fitting a Poisson GLM
suppressWarnings(
  model2 <- glm(y ~ x, 
                data = df,
                family = poisson(link='log'))
)
#make predictions (this may be the same as predictions_mod2)
preds <- predict(model2, type = "response")

#making CI predictions
predictions_mod2 = predict(model2, df, se.fit = TRUE, type = 'response')

#calculate confidence intervals limit
upper_mod2 = predictions_mod2$fit+1.96*predictions_mod2$se.fit 
lower_mod2 = predictions_mod2$fit-1.96*predictions_mod2$se.fit

#combining into a df
predframe = data.frame(lwr=lower_mod2,upr=upper_mod2, x = df$x, y = df$y)

#plot model with 95% confidence intervals using ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = predframe, aes(ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x, preds), col = 'blue')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>